# Loop all combinations of multiple variables

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to see all the possible output of a function with multiple variables. To create all possible combinations I iterate which create tuples. But I am not sure how to use these tuples inside the function inside the loop. The code below throw an error.

THE FUNCTION:

```
def daily_volume_historical(symbol, comparison_symbol, all_data=False, limit=7, aggregate=1, exchange=''):
    url = 'https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/histoday?fsym={}&tsym={}&limit={}&aggregate={}'\
            .format(symbol.upper(), comparison_symbol.upper(), limit, aggregate)
    if exchange:
        url += '&e={}'.format(exchange)
    if all_data:
        url += '&allData=true'
    page = requests.get(url)
    data = page.json()['Data']
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    df.drop(df.index[-1], inplace=True)
    df['timestamp'] = [datetime.fromtimestamp(d) for d in df.time]
    df.set_index('timestamp')
    return df
```

THE CODE:

```
quoted = 'USD', 'EUR',  'JPY',  'SGD',  'HKD',  'IDR',  'AUD',  'PHP',  'CNY',  'INR',  'BTC',  'ETH',  'QASH', 'BCH',  'GUSD', 'USDC', 'GBP'
liqud_mar = 'Bitbank', 'Bitfinex', 'Bithumb', 'BitMEX', 'Bitstamp', 'Cexio', 'Coinbase', 'Coincheck', 'Gemini', 'itBit', 'Kraken', 'OKCoin'
p = list(itertools.product(quoted, liqud_mar))

d_volu = [] 
for x in p:
    volu = daily_volume_historical('QTUM', x[0], exchange= x[1]).volumefrom
    d_volu.append
d_volu = pd.concat(d_volu, axis=1)
```

THE ERROR:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./urlcombin5.py", line 26, in <module>
    volu = daily_volume_historical('QTUM', x[0], exchange= x[1]).volumefrom
  File "./urlcombin5.py", line 15, in daily_volume_historical
    df.drop(df.index[-1], inplace=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2084, in __getitem__
    return getitem(key)
IndexError: index -1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

Comment: Can you show the error?

Comment: the error is there because there is no data to concatenate but i am sure it should retrieve some data.

Comment: You can request the data by other means and verify that it is or isnt empty. If it can be empty you may need to handle that case.

Comment: It is helpful to include the full error traceback, as it not only shows the error message but also the line of code that caused the error and the call stack.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
for a,b in [(a,b) for a in quoted for b in liqud_mar]:
    volu = daily_volume_historical('QTUM', a, exchange= b).volumefrom
    d_volu.append
```

Comment: Sorry I have to say that the dataframe is empty after running this. I am trying to figure out why this happens.

Comment: Are you getting expected values in variables a and b?

Comment: I found out the answer as i posted below. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is as follow:

```
combinations = list(itertools.product(base, quoted))
d_volu = []
for a,b in combinations:
try:
    volu = daily_volume_historical(a, b, exchange= 'CCCAGG').set_index('timestamp').volumefrom
    d_volu.append(volu.rename(a))
except:
    pass
d_volu = pd.concat(d_volu, axis=1)
d_volu = d_volu.groupby(d_volu.columns.values, axis=1).sum()
```